# Ubuntu Development on 2nd Gen Nexus 7?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I was reading the steps over at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/Installation but I don't see the 2nd gen Nexus 7 ever mentioned.  It's also not in the FAQ, and before I follow through with it I just wanted to make sure this is supported on the 2nd gen Nexus as well.  I see no reason it shouldn't work, just wanted to make sure before I give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

It won't work. The hardware is completely different and you will likely end up with a soft-bricked device. The CPUs are different (grouper/tilapia has Tegra 3, razor has Snapdragon 600), and so are the kernels.